# Error column not found, but I did not declare the column?

Tags: laravel

I'm inserting a record to a polymorphic imageable table, however it says column thread_id not found. I have not declared this thread_id column and I don't know where it's pulling it from. Here is the code it's trying to run.

```
protected static function bootRecordImage()
    {
        if (auth()->guest()) return;

            foreach (static::getMethodToRecord() as $event) {

            static::$event(function ($model) use ($event) {
                $body = request()->body;

                preg_match_all('/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si', $body, $matches);
            
                $images = $matches[1];

                if($event == 'created') {
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        $model->images()->create([
                            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                            'imageable_id' => $model->id,
                            'imageable_type' => get_class($model),
                            'path' => $image
                        ]);
                    }
                }
                if($event == 'deleting') {
                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                        $model->images()->delete([
                            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                            'imageable_id' => $model->id,
                            'imageable_type' => get_class($model),
                            'path' => $image
                        ]);
                        if (File::exists(public_path($image))) {
                            File::delete(public_path($image));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

My store method:

```
public function store(Request $request, Channel $channel, Spam $spam)
    {
        if (!auth()->user()) {
            return back()->withInput()->with('flash', 'Sorry! You must be logged in to perform this action.');
        }
        if (!auth()->user()->confirmed) {
            return back()->withInput()->with('flash', 'Sorry! You must first confirm your email address.');
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'channel_id' => 'required|exists:channels,id',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required'
            // yes it's required, but it also needs to exist on the channels model, specifically on the id
        ]);

        $response = Zttp::asFormParams()->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
            'secret' => config('services.recaptcha.secret'),
            'response' => $request->input('g-recaptcha-response'),
            'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        ]);

        // dd($response->json());
        if (! $response->json()['success']) {
            throw new \Exception('Recaptcha failed');
        }

        $spam->detect(request('title'));
        $spam->detect(request('body'));

        $thread = Thread::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'channel_id' => request('channel_id'),
            'title' => request('title'),
            'body' => request('body'),
            //'slug' => str_slug(request('title'))
        ]);

        return redirect('/forums/' .  $thread->channel->slug . '/' . $thread->slug);
    }
```

As you can see, no where is a thread_id mentioned, yet in the error it looks like it's trying to insert into a thread_id column that I've never declared.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the polymorphic relation in the model and the trait. Remove it from the Model and you're good to go.